# Is there an Excel function for copying all results without blank cells, while searching a match in another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, copy, match

Let's imagine I have a list of Companies that each has various alarms, see list below. This is normally a very long list.

. | column A | column B

1 |Company  | Alarm Type

2 |BB   ...........| alarm-1

3 |AA   ...........| alarm-7

4 |CC   ...........| alarm-32

5 |BB   ...........| alarm-4

6 |AA   ...........| alarm-1

7 |CC   ...........| alarm-7

8 |BB   ...........| alarm-33

9 |CC   ...........| alarm-1

10 |BB  ..........| alarm-88

I need a list of all alarm types that a company has. I define the lookup value in cell C1, so I can change the search term from AA to CC or BB, depending on my needs at the moment.

In column D, I want a return list without any blank cells.

I have tried the simple IF(Company=lookup value;Alarm Type;"") but that leaves me blank lines.
The same happens when I used INDEX and MATCH

#### For example, if I search for Company CC, i want results like this:

. | column DD

1 | Alarm Type

2 | alarm-32

3 | alarm-7

4 | alarm-1

#### What I do not want, is this:

. | column DD

1 | Alarm Type

2 |

3 |

4 | alarm-32

5 |

6 |

7 | alarm-7

8 |

9 | alarm-1

10 |

Comment: What about using Pivot Tables to resume your data?. That way you could get easily a list where you can see what alarms got each company.

Comment: why don't you just use Filter (or even Advanced Filter) in Column A, or use a pivot table and filter the alarms by company as you want? Let me know if you want to see a demonstration.

Comment: I do not want any manual involvement here. I will actually have those lookup values and results on different sheets, and those data will be exported into another document every day, when i get new data (the data is imported through SQL - I want the entire thing to be fully automatic, without manual filter settings). I'll explore the pivot option, thanks for the idea.

Comment: and if you are using Excel 2010 or later versions, try exploring Power Query which is ideal for importing large volume of data from other sources to excel and transform/edit the data efficiently over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this through formulas you could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,AGGREGATE(15,3,($A$1:$A$10=$D$2)*ROW($A$1:$A$10),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,"<>"&$D$2)+ROW(A1))),"")
```

Drag down to `E10`

---

If you are talkin about a very long list, this formula might slow down your worksheet quite significantly. Instead maybe use one helper column:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(A2=$E$2,ROW(),"")
```

Formula in 'F2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL($C$2:$C$10,ROW(A1))),"")
```

Drag both down.

---

I do agree with above comments that a Pivot-Table is a powerful tool which you might prefer over worksheet-functions when you talk about a very long list.